# Azure Load Testing - Load Tests Return 'Not Applicable' Failed status despite showing as successful in Exported Result Files & AppInsights

Tags: azure, load-testing

We are currently running a POC on the new Azure Load Testing feature (currently in preview) as a resource to run our jMeter tests against an in development API.

Unfortunately we are hitting a few problems with the output results displayed within a test run, namely the tests always fail with no start, end and duration time along with a 'Not Applicable' status when running against the APIs despite all tests running successfully directly within the jMeter GUI. The same tests when run in the Azure Load Testing tool also appear to show as 'Passed' when exporting results from the test screen.

Has anyone experienced this before and would be able to help, as this tool could be exactly what we are looking for if we can get it to output the correct results.

Our jMeter test is fairly simple and obtains a validation token which is used in the latter request, I have manually verified this is all authenticating correctly and the variables we are using in these tests are being correctly populated when run in Azure. Note this issue appears in both our GraphQL and REST API tests.

See attached screenshots:

**Test Result**
[image]

**Exported Result**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

In my .jmx I changed the **Thread Group** to a **jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group**.

I also set up criteria tests.
[criteria tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWPqa.png)

Now the status of my tests is Done
[status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K16OU.png)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately we have since tried adding the Ultimate Thread Group plugin to our tests, but we still appear to get the same results.  

[Latest Test Run Results](https://imgur.com/a/IZNBb13)